# How to check if a c++ vector already contains and element with a specific value (in this case a struct)?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I need to check if an element with a specific value already exists in a c++ vector before adding a new one (to avoid duplicates).

I checked everything and this solution (simplified code below) seems to be the most efficient, if only it did work.

The problem I'm having is specifically with this line:

"if(std::find(positions.begin(), positions.end(), pos) != positions.end())",

which gives me compile errors inside the  library, saying "Invalid operands to binary expression ('position' and 'const position')".

I know I am a bit of a newbie in c++ and I am sorry if this is e bit of a dumb question, but can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Is it the fact that the value is a struct? Does it have anything to do with values vs. pointers/references (I suspect it does)?

```
struct position
{
    int column;
    int row;
};


int main ()
{
    std::vector<position> positions = {{0,0}, {0,1}, {0,2}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {1,2}};

    position pos = {2,1};

    if(std::find(positions.begin(), positions.end(), pos) != positions.end())
    {

        positions.push_back(pos);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Value is already present" << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I am clueless and really stuck with this, which is preventing me to advance in my project.

Does any one have an idea of what am I doing wrong or how should I do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: "can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong?" - well, for a start, you're not actually describing the *problem.* Is it a compile time error? Is it not being added when it should be? Is it being added when it shouldn't be? Does your computer laugh maniacally when you try to run the program? :-)

Comment: It's a compile  error inside the <algorithm> library. It points to this particular code: {
    for (; __first != __last; ++__first)
        if (*__first == __value_)
            break;
    return __first;
} and says: "Invalid operands to binary expression ('position' and 'const position')"

Comment: It's better to provide exact error messages. They might look like gibberish, but they are not.

Comment: Thanks, just edited my comment above accordingly...any idea?

Comment: See the answer below.

Comment: I'm sure that the error message should say that there's a problem with the comparison `==`. If not in the first line then in one of the following. When asking questions about code that lead to build errors, always include the *full* and *complete* error output in the question itself, copy-pasted as text. Please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: As for possible ways to solve your problem, you could also use [`std::find_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) and instead of a "value" to compare against you provide a callable object (for example a [lambda function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda). This is very useful if you (for some reason) can't implement an `operator==` for your class.

Comment: Do you absolutely need `std::vector`? Do you need to access items in the same order they are added? If not, I suggest you take a look at `std::set` which by definition contains *sorted unique* items: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Two things are wrong here (there may be others but these are the relevant ones).

First, there is no equality operator in your structure that would allow `find` to compare items. This can be added with something like:

```
struct position {
    int column;
    int row;
    bool operator==(const position &other) const {
        return column == other.column && row == other.row;
    }
};
```

Second, the sense of your comparison is wrong. The `find` will return `end` if the item is *not* found, so your `if` section should be:

```
if (std::find(positions.begin(), positions.end(), pos) == positions.end()) {
    positions.push_back(pos);
} else {
    std::cout << "Value is already present" << std::endl;
}
```

---

For completeness, here's a full program that shows what happens when you try to add a non-existant element three times:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct position {
    int column;
    int row;
    bool operator==(const position &other) const {
        return column == other.column && row == other.row;
    }
};

int main () {
    std::vector<position> vec = {};

    position pos = {2,1};
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        if (std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), pos) == vec.end()) {
            std::cout << "Adding value" << std::endl;
            vec.push_back(pos);
        } else {
            std::cout << "Value is already present" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

From the ouput, you can see only the first one actually inserts:

```
Adding value
Value is already present
Value is already present
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case, but in general `operator==` should be `const`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat: actually I would say it *does* matter, as would my work mates who keep bringing those types of things up in my code reviews :-) Have added it in.

Comment: @paxdiablo, thank you so much!! Of course you are right and everything makes sense now. Too many hours in front of the screen and too little smarts on my side...;) you helped me a lot in this, thanks!!!